# Ranking in Teradata- SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to rank my sales data using the rank() over function . Here is my code :

```
Select 
Category as CAT
,units*cost as COST_SALES
,units*retail as RETAIL_COST
,units as UNITS_SOLD
,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY 3 DESC ) AS RANKING

from Table 

Where date between current_date-7 and current_date
group by 1
```

When I get my result it is unordered and shows rank 1 for all the categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use column references in the window functions.  You need to name the columns explicitly:

```
Select Category as CAT, units*cost as COST_SALES, units*retail as RETAIL_COST,
       units as UNITS_SOLD,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Categroy ORDER BY units*retail DESC ) AS RANKING
from Table 
Where date between current_date-7 and current_date
group by Category;
```

Comment: Teradata will allow you to use aliases within the same query though. So you could use `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Category order by Retail_Cost)`.

Comment: Andrew . . . That's interesting.  How would it handle something like:  `select (x*x) as x, x from (select 10 as x) a`.  ANSI does not require an order of evaluation of expressions, and most databases do not guarantee it.

Comment: Teradata will execute that statement, and it returns two columns named x. However, `select x from (select (x*x) as x, x from (select 10 as x) a) t` will fail with an error about 'Duplication of column X`.  Teradata has a couple of extensions to ANSI SQL.